# Rails erb syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm working around the erb template and couldn't get the following code working. I've tried to remove the quotes around the nested tag, but no luck. I'm using Rails 4.0.

```
<%= image_tag("<%= project.image_path%>", alt: "project") %>
```

Error:

```
_project.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected '>'...e_append='", alt: "project") %>';@output_buffer.to_s
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

You are still in a rails function

```
<%= image_tag( project.image_path, alt: "project") %>
```

should work

Comment: Great! Thanks for fast response.